# Modify all network packets sent over the interface

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

In want to modify the TCP/IP portion of the Linux kernel where i can to intercept every packet going out to each interface. I need to intercept them and modify the IPv6 destination Options header. I am not sure how to start with this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
N

Answer (score 2):

You can modify packets using a Python library called scapy. It is not necessary to modify kernel code in order to do so. However, keep in mind that you must set up a Man-in-the-middle in order to sniff a communication.

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/